# write script code in code behind file and get value from it

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am Using this script and this return information related to my ip address

```
<script language="Javascript" src="http://gd.geobytes.com/gd?after=-1&variables=GeobytesCountry,GeobytesCity,GeobytesRegion,GeobytesLatitude,GeobytesLongitude">
</script>


<script language="Javascript">
    document.write("<p>Welcome to visitors from " + sGeobytesCity + ", " + sGeobytesCountry + ", " + sGeobytesRegion + ", " + sGeobytesLatitude + ", " + sGeobytesLongitude);
</script>
```

Is there any way that i used this script in code behind file (aspx.cs) and store them into some variable...

Like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string city = sGeobytesCity;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an asp literal control.

```
document.write('<p>Welcome to visitors from <asp:Literal id="sGeobytesCity" runat="server"' />);
```

And then in your code behind.

```
sGeobytesCity.Text = HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode("yourCityNameHere");
```

The main purpose of the javascript encoder is to remove any single apostrophes or double quotes which could prematurely terminate the string, thus allowing for a javascript error or malicious injection.

Answer (score 0):

try to save the data in your script in `hidden` input `runat=server` then from code behind you can access this hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hiddenData" />
```

then

```
string data = hiddenEntityId.Value; //to get the data back
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it isn't simple at all. In javascript, the browser is handling all the 'open a web request, get the result' for you. *And* it's running the javascript for you to put values into the variables. 
In code behind you're doing it yourself. This example is from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx

```
// Create a request for the URL.        
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://gd.geobytes.com/gd?after=-1&variables=GeobytesCountry,GeobytesCity,GeobytesRegion,GeobytesLatitude,GeobytesLongitude");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
var responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
reader.Close ();
dataStream.Close ();
response.Close ();
```

*Then* you would have to look at the responseFromServer and work out how to get the data you need from the response. OR find out if the website has a different api you can access.